# How to automatic specify images in content added to gallery

Tags: gallery

How to automatic specify images in content added to gallery?
my image link is external link

i think use specify images by class
my specify images class is:

```
class="s-slide"
```

i crawled another site (non wordpress cms) and on other site specify images show on gallery now i want specify images crawled in my site (wordpress cms) on wp_gallery or anothere jqury gallery

Comment: What do you mean by "specify images". Specify them for what?

Comment: i crawled another site (no wordpress cms) and on other site specify images show on gallery
now i want specify images crawled in my site (wordpress cms) on wp_gallery or anothere jqury gallery

Comment: Are you saying you want to include images that are hosted on a totally different, non-WP site, on your WP site in a WP gallery? You can't. WP galleries contain images that are in your own Media Library.

Comment: if can't. WP galleries contain images. Can I show gallery images through the CSS and class specific images? Or there is a plugin for gallery in WordPress that can be defined as a CSS class?